# fetching data in Vue beforeEach hook and store by dispatch an action

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, frontend

I save the data fecthing in beforeEach hook in store by dispatching an action. Then I want to use them in a component.What comfuses me is that  occasionally the component was created before that action executed which cause me losing these data and having errors below.

[image: dispatching action in beforeEnter]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share that button component code

Comment: `props: { isOrg: { type: Boolean, required: true } }`

Comment: i guess this prop will come from the userinfo and  its async request so vue try to render the button but its not able to pass this prop into it as  request is pending (as its ajax request i assume), you should define some flag which will set to false by default and only become true after you fetched all details and based on that flag, conditionally you can render that button or event that portion.

Comment: I realized my mistake. And thank you for your answer.

Comment: cool, glad to see you got your solution :)